# How can I convert json type to dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have DataFrame like this.

```
id     name   actions   
Obj1   val1   [{'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '40'}, {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '546''}
Obj2   val1   [{'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '10'}, {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '200''}   
Obj4   val1   [{'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '20'}, {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '100''}
```

I have to convert like this.

```
id     name   link_click.   page_engagement
Obj1   val1   40             546
Obj2   val1   10             200   
Obj4   val1   20             100
```

Is this possible with pandas? If so, how can I manage to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pd.concat([df.drop(['actions'], axis=1), df['actions'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks for answer. but how can I control json type([{'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '40'}, {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '546''})

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Did you run the code?